# kicking user from Client.users.fetch()

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am looking to kick a user via a bot, I have their id and am using Client.users.fetch(ID) to get there user. The error is ".kick not a function".

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
var User = Client.users.fetch(ID);

User.then(function(Result) {
    Result.kick();
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Only members can be kicked, not users.  You can use `<guild>.member(User).kick()` instead.

Comment: Would User still be var User = Client.users.fetch(ID);?

Comment: <guild> doesn't work at all? I even tried message.guild and it doesn't work

Comment: If your function is async, try `const User = await client.users.fetch('ID here')` and then `message.guild.member(User).kick()`.  Don't forget to make sure your ID is a string, not a number.

Comment: "await is only available in async function"

Answer (score 0):

You can actually bypass having to get the user object since `<guild>.member()` accepts a user *resolvable,* which includes the ID as a snowflake (string).  Assuming you have a `message` object, you can use `message.guild.member('ID here').kick()`

Comment: message.guild.member(Choice).kick();

I get the error: "Unable to read property kick of null". Choice is a string and the correct id.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** kick a **user** in discord, you must understand the differences between a member and a user. The following possibilities are listed below:

a) You are trying to find the user and kick it from **ever** server that is possible.

```js
var id = 'YOUR_ID_HERE';
<client>.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => { // Parses every guild
  if(guild.members.cache.has(id)){ // Checks if member exists
    var member = guild.members.cache.get(id); // Fetches the member
    if(member.kickable){ // Checks if kickable
      member.kick() // Kicks the member
    }
  }
})
```

b) kicking from current guild:

```js
var id = 'YOUR_ID_HERE';
if(message.guild){ // If you are in a guild
  let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(id); // Fetches member
  if(member && member.kickable){ // Checks if member exists and is kickable
    member.kick() // Kicks member
  }
}
```

c) you are trying to kick from a targeted guild

```js
var guildID = 'YOUR_TARGETTED_GUILD_ID';
var id = 'YOUR_TARGETTED_USERID';

const guild = <client>.guilds.cache.get(guildID); // Gets guild
if(guild){ // Checks if exists
  let member = guild.members.cache.get(id); // Gets member
  if(member){ // If member exists
    if(member.kickable){ // Checks if kickable
      member.kick() // Kicks member
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Apparently member is nil? The id is literally a string copied from right clicking on there profile and pressing copy id. The whole guild thing is fine, and I just want to kick it from the current guild.

Comment: Oh the current guild is b) you would have to change the id every time you use it, or you can use an argument parse, e.g.
var id = args[0];